# How to get all the materials assigned to a GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, we can get the material that the GameObject has with the following code.

```
Material myMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
```

But with the above code, we can only get one material per GameObject.

However, in actually, Unity GameObjects can have more than one material.

As shown in the image below
[image]

There can be more than one material per GameObject if it is assigned on a face-by-face basis.

I tried to get multiple materials with the code below but it didn't work.

```
List<Material> myMaterials = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
```

Is there a way to get multiple materials assigned to a GameObject?

Comment: What about a short look into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html)? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Renderer.Materials`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html

```
List<Material> myMaterials = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials.ToList();
```